# How to retrieve current windows user name on client side in xampp without asp.net

Tags: javascript, php, python-3.x, html

I am trying to retrieve windows current user name in my website for displaying it.
I know it is possible in asp.net 
by

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

How can i achieve this without asp.net by using maybe javascript, python or php.

Also in php using

```
getenv("username")
```

gives me current user of the server system, but i want client side system's username

Comment: lots of options are there, are you looking for session or cookies ?

Comment: well anything would work. please provide a solution for either of it @Bira

Comment: do you use any framework ? can I see the login code ?

Comment: i have currently hosted my website on xampp and their isn't any login code as such i was planning to get the windows username and using same name to login via ldap like if it is present in my AD i will allow it.